# Pure CSS patterned background?

Tags: html, css

I have a body tag that needs serious decorating. I want to refrain from downloading images and/or using libraries. I have tried using many different background-colors to decorate my body tag, but it is just not working.

Here's what I need:

1. Pure CSS striped pattern (no images)
2. Pure CSS spotted pattern (polkadot, no images)
3. Way to split my body tag into four quadrants, each with different background
4. Generate pure css combo of 1 & 2?

I have searched for the answers to these, but I could only find image generators. I know there is a way to make gradients, but is there a way to make other pure CSS patterns, or should I download images?

Comment: Do you mean something like this https://css-tricks.com/stripes-css/ ?

Comment: yeah, but that is only stripes. I know how to do gradient and somewhat stripes, but other patterns is what I need. I also need a combination of stripes and dots...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS3 background property to design almost anything you like, there are also websites that can generate css codes like this one for example:

```
body {
background-color:#ccc;
background-image: linear-gradient(30deg, #445 12%, transparent 12.5%, transparent 87%, #445 87.5%, #445),
linear-gradient(150deg, #445 12%, transparent 12.5%, transparent 87%, #445 87.5%, #445),
linear-gradient(30deg, #445 12%, transparent 12.5%, transparent 87%, #445 87.5%, #445),
linear-gradient(150deg, #445 12%, transparent 12.5%, transparent 87%, #445 87.5%, #445),
linear-gradient(60deg, #99a 25%, transparent 25.5%, transparent 75%, #99a 75%, #99a), 
linear-gradient(60deg, #99a 25%, transparent 25.5%, transparent 75%, #99a 75%, #99a);
background-size:80px 140px;
background-position: 0 0, 0 0, 40px 70px, 40px 70px, 0 0, 40px 70px;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a website that can generate something like this?

Comment: this code if from http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/ but you can just google exactly what you need and try to find it in other websites too..

Comment: This is perfect... In reality, all I needed was that link, not the code you put there. :)

Comment: It's just a fast example for CSS background property. to learn more details about this one you can read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient